# Excluding js.map files from project when .ts file is present

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have this in .vscode\settings.json:

```
"files.exclude": {
        "**/.git": true,
        "**/.DS_Store": true,
        "**/*.js": { "when": "$(basename).ts"},
        "**/*.js.map": { "when": "$(basename).ts"}
}
```

The .js line is working fine, but the last line with the .js.map pattern is not working even if left alone. Why is that?

Answer (score 7):

I use the following filter:

```
    "files.exclude": {
        "**/.git": true,
        "**/.DS_Store": true,
        "**/*.js": { "when": "$(basename).ts" },
        "**/*.js.map": { "when": "$(basename)" }
    }
```

This works because the transpilation result is an js-file and in addition an js.map-file. So the filter hides all map-files if a js-file is present and all js-files if a ts-file is there.

I like this one because my typescript transpiler runs in a background task and if there something goes wrong then the js.map-file pops up because of the missing corresponding js-file.

Comment: Nice one, the "$(basename)" without the ".ts" extension works, as it matches "filename.js". Unfortunately, this trick won't work for, say, .min.css files compiled from scss, as the extensions are the other way around (".js.map" vs. ".min.css") - the ".min" is never matched.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
"**/*.map": { "when": "$(basename).ts"}
```

Or if you want to hide all map files:

```
"**/*.map": {}
```

Comment: The second one works. Which is OK, but it should work with the conditional one as well.

Answer (score 0):

ver 1.4
File->Preferences->Workspace

settings.json

```
 "files.exclude":{
   "**/*.js": { "when": "$(basename).ts"}
   ,"**/*.map": true
   }
```

You  don't need to see .map files anyway